# VS Code on Macbook Stopped Using SSH key for Git Authentication

Tags: git

So I've been using SSH keys on my macbook/windows devices to push to my repos on github.

My what I usually do is a `git status`, `git add`, `git commit -m 'info'`, then a `git push origin dev`.  After that, I am prompted to provide my SSH password.

As of today, when I use VS code on my macbook to push; I get a prompt on the window to enter my username, then enter my password; which was not what was happening a few days ago. I get the following error message:

```
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/mellowmoo/progressiveBudget.git/'
mellowmoo@Muhaimens-MacBook-Pro progressiveBudget %
```

When I check github, it says that the SHH key on my macbook is still set, and had successfully pushed a few days ago.  How should I go about troubleshooting this issue.

From my understanding of this error message, it is not using my SSH key for authentication, it is using something else.  How do I make VS code go back to using my SSH key for authentication.

Thank you for your help, I'm relatively new to coding; I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `origin` remote is set up to use HTTPS instead of SSH, that’s why it’s asking for a personal access token. Try `git remote -v` to confirm the URL of your origin remote.
You can use `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:user/repo.git` to instead use the SSH url.